# Is there any life cycle method for understand the new state key added to component state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

UPDATED:

I have a question for you. In my react app I have basic state like below.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: "Hello";
    }
}
```

And think that I have button and onClick event I add new dynamic key to state.
Let's say [key] = "newValue" and "val"= 1.

```
onClickEvent(){
    let splitArray = value.split('_');
    let key = splitArray[0];
    let val = splitArray[1];
    this.setState({
        [key]: val
    });
}

render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.onClickEvent}>Click</button>
             <input value={} />
        </div>
        );
}
```

Everything is Ok until now. But I don't know how to use this dynamically created new state property which in case my example [key].

In render method, my input value is empty because I don't have value in the state.

After the click event, I add new state key and I want that my render like this.

```
render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.onClickEvent}>Click</button>
            <input value={this.state.[key]} />
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Is there any life cycle method of react component, detects the added new state property ? Because I want to use that newly created state property.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Store the key in your state too.

```
this.setState({
  [key]: val,
  updatedKey: key
})
```

Then you can implement `componentDidUpdate` and use the key to read the new state value.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  let { updatedKey } = this.state;
  let val = this.state[updatedKey];
}
```

Comment: I know in componentDidUpdate() method,  I can see the  {updated} key value.
Actually my question is this. 

I also have <input type="text" value={} onChange={anotherEventHandler} />;

I want to set as a value, this {updated} in the state. But firstly, i don't know the this.state.???? thats why my input value is empty. Then I know that I have new key in the state. But now, I cannot set it to the input value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. Can't you just read `this.state.updatedKey` inside your `anotherEventHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

You could use the following

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a life cycle method to get that value, put the key in the state as well:

```
onClickEvent(){
    const [currentKey, value] = value.split('_');
    this.setState({
        currentKey,
        [currentKey]: val
    });
}
```

and access it in the next render cycle with:

```
this.state[this.state.currentKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ComponentDidUpdate is what you are looking for.
You can detect new key of state like this.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  var prev = Object.keys(prevState).sort();
  var current = Object.keys(this.state).sort();
  if(JSON.stringify(prev) === JSON.stringify(current)){
    do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Yes, I detect the new key of state but I don't know how many keys I will have and also I don't know their key names. I will use these as a value of input. So I want to give like that <input  value={this.state.blablabla}.